# Perpetual Option Paying Chooser Option

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, american-options, exotics, differential-equations

A perpetual option solves the ODE
$$rSV_S+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2V_{SS}-rV=0$$
The general solution is $$V(S)=aS+bS^{\gamma}$$ where $\gamma=-\frac{2r}{\sigma^2}<0$.

---

For an **American put** option with payoff $K-S$, we find $a=0$ because we require $V(S)=0$ as $S\to\infty$. We find the free boundary (exercise point, $S^*$) and the remaining free parameter ($b$) by value-matching and smooth-pasting of $V(S)$ with the payoff $K-S$ at $S=S^*$, that is
\begin{align}
b(S^*)^{\gamma} &= K-S^* \\
b\gamma(S^*)^{\gamma-1} &= -1
\end{align}
The option value is then
\begin{align}
V(S)=\begin{cases} K-S &if\; S<S^* \\
bS^{\gamma} &if\; S\geq S^* \end{cases}
\end{align}

---

**Question:** What happens if the option pays $\max(K_1-S,K_2-2S)=K_2-2S+\max(S+K_1-K_2,0)$ instead of $K-S$? The payoff now resembles a chooser option (between two puts). We still require $a=0$ such that $V(S)=0$ as $S\to\infty$. But how to proceed? I don't think it's as simple as finding $b$ and $S^*$ by solving value-matching and smooth-pasting condition and setting
\begin{align}
V(S)=\begin{cases} \max(K_1-S,K_2-2S) &if\; S<S^* \\
bS^{\gamma} &if\; S\geq S^* \end{cases}
\end{align}